How many days until Halloween?
The decoration below displays the number of days until Halloween using two cubes, with each face showing one digit. By rotating and rearranging the cubes, what is the largest number from which you can continually (i.e., representing all intermediate integers) count down to Halloween ("00")? Numbers less than 10 are displayed with a leading "0".


Surely we need a list of digits each cube has on their faces?

Are the numbers aligned exactly like in the image? And does "rearranging" mean switching the places of the cubes?

Are all the digits different?

A very similar problem here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48453/calendar-cubes-are-impossible?rq=1

I'm fine with deleting my answer if the question is judged as unclear or too similar to the one in the link.

It is Ok, just clarify if 6 can be used as 9.

What's the lateral thinking tag for, do you think?

@Nautilus, so reusing the linked question and solution the answer is 32.

If you look at the number above the 1, it could be interpreted as either a 2 or a 7.

@Kate Gregory Then it would be 43.

This is what I came up with:

 Cube 1 sides: 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6
 Cube 2 sides: 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8

If we…

 …use the 6 upside down as 9…

…the maximum possible countdown timer is…

 …32, since 33 is unreachable without a second 3.

 All values in the 10s and 20s are reachable since there are 2 ones, 2 twos and at least one of every other digit.


Not convinced about this one since in the photo 3 and 4 are both on the same cube, and 7 on a different one.

@Bladeski: There is more than one way of arranging the numbers on the cubes to get all numbers up to (this answer's maximum). Just because the one in the picture is different doesn't mean this one is wrong :)

@Bladeski In this solution we can place all of the numbers greater than 2 wherever we please. Simply swap the 3 or 4 to the other block to get something that matches the picture.

Utilizing an admittedly questionable trick, it's possible to get up to

 35

With cube sides:

 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8

And also making

 6 pull double digit duty as 9 (or vice versa)

This is the maximum because

 We need 0, 1, 2 on each cube to represent 00, 11, and 22 respectively which only gives us 3 faces on each cube to customize. We need 4, 5, and 8 to be on the cube opposite of the 3 for my trick to work which means we need 3, 6, and 7 to be on the other cube. This arrangement allows us to count down from 35 -> 00. At this point, you're probably wondering about 33. Let me explain below.

The questionable trick to obtain

 33.
 Since we're dealing with 3D cubes and not just digits and because the question says that we can rotate and rearrange the cubes, but doesn't put any restrictions on how, we can arrange the 3 to partially occlude the left half of the 8 so that it looks like a 3. Here's a mockup I did in paint 3D to give the idea 



Neat. Can we use this trick to also squeeze a free 0 out of the top/bottom of the 8? Not quite as clean, but arguably works.

Combining All the Tricks
There are three tricks which have been discussed so far.

 A 6 can be turned upside-down to make a 9. (By several authors)
 A 7 can be written in an ornamental script such that it resembles a 2 when turned upside-down. (By Kate Gregory)
 An 8 in the unit's digit can be partially occluded by the ten's digit to make a 3. (By Redbomber)

If we combine all of these tricks, our dice are:

 {0,1,2,7,3,4,5}, {0,1,2,7,3 (units digit only),8,4,6,9}

The lowest number that cannot be represented is

 55

Thus, the countdown can thus start on

 September 7th, with 54 days to Halloween.


Based on expanding earlier answers about the use of fancy fonts:
Retreading previous ground:

We can obviously flip the number 6 to be the number 9.  As was pointed out earlier, the font used in the cubes pictured in the question allows the number 2 to double as 7 — however, depending on font, the number 1 can fulfil the same function.

However, less obviously:

With a carefully designed font, we can also flip the number 4 to be the number 5


 (Please excuse the very shoddy artistic talents on display) 


This can give us the following two cubes:

 Cube 1: 0, 1, 2 OR 7, 3, 4 OR 5, 6 OR 9
Cube 2: 0, 1, 2 OR 7, 3, 4 OR 5, 8

Which will all us to represent all of the numbers up to

 65

Which will be displayed on the date

 27th August

Of course, the next limit would be

 If anyone can design a 6 that flips through 180° to resemble an 8, rather than a 9 — bringing the limit up to 87.  Or, even, if they can design a 3 that flips to resemble an 8, allowing us to reach 99 — or 100 if that 3 can also look like two "0"s when rotated through 90°

